# Are structs value types because their structure is known at compile time?

Tags: c#

So, each struct contains only values for value types, and/or references to reference types, which are of a known size.

So a demo struct:

```
struct demo
{
        public int a = 7;
        public string b = "test";
}
```

Would appear in memory (vaguely) like this:

```
struct demo
{
    public int    a = 00000000000000000000000000000111
    public string b = 0x80484f0
}
```

And as a result, the struct is a value type that stores its contents in memory allocated on the stack.

I just needed to clarify this, as I'm not sure how else a struct can be a value type.

Comment: But you can say the same about classes, so that's not the reason.

Comment: Classes are allocated on the heap, just the pointer (reference) is allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structs can be treated as value types (as in, they are copied when passed as arguments, and stored inline in an array, etc) because their size is known at the jitter's compile time (or, to be more precise, because their size can be inferred from a variable/field's declared type).

*Whyyy* is their size known at compile time? It's not because "each struct contains only values for value types, and/or references to reference types, which are of a known size." - the same could be said for reference types.

Their size is known at compile time *because* inheritance is disallowed. If you could subclass `demo`, then a variable of type `demo` could point to an object much larger than `demo`.

Pretend for a second you *could* subclass structs, and remember that value types are stored inline in an array:

```
//4 bytes (1 integer)
public struct A {int x;} 

//8 bytes (2 integers)
public struct B : A {int y;} 

//An array of A's with enough space for 1 instance of A, that is, 4 bytes
A[] array = new A[1];

//instances of B don't fit in the array
a[0] = new B();
```

As Matthew points out in the comments, C++ allows you to do this, *but* field `B.y` will be trimmed and lost.

Comment: Although it's worth pointing out that in C++ you *can* inherit from a struct - and yet you can still put them into arrays and push them onto the stack and treat them as value types... (and also make all kinds of horrible mistakes as a result ;)

Comment: @MatthewWatson It's been years since I last used C++ but, correct me if I'm wrong, if you do that, the struct's contents will be trimmed and the derived type's extra fields will be lost, right?

Comment: Yep, the horrible "slicing problem" (which also afflicts C++ classes too)

Comment: No, their size isn't known at the compile time, because that would mean `sizeof(DateTime)` gets compiled to a constant, but (in IL) it is `sizeof [mscorlib]System.DateTime`. If the compiler relied on the size of the structure when compiling a code that uses it, it would get incompatible (if the structure is in a DLL) as the structure definition changes (affecting its size, not behavior, like additional fields). What you mean is probably the size of the structure is taken into account when the CLR manipulates with it on the stack. During run-time, the size of a value type is known perfectly.

Comment: @IllidanS4 Yes, that was an over simplification, but then I added this to my answer: "or, to be more precise, because their size can be inferred from a variable/field's declared type". The size of a pointer, for example, is not known at compile-time - it'll be 4 bytes on 32bit systems and 8 bytes on 64bit systems. Another way to look at it: the size is known at the jitter's compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

As you say it stores its content on the stack and not on the heap. Thus it has to be a value type.

Comment: But value types are often stored on the heap. And reference types can be stored on the stack, as an optimization (I believe Java does this).

Comment: @svick Reference types aren't stored on the stack, I don't see how this could prove to be an optimalization.

Comment: @IllidanS4 Yes, they aren't in any implementation of .Net that I know of. But they *can be*, thanks to [escape analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis).

Comment: @svick Hmm, yes, this could be possible, but how exactly is storing object memory on the stack more efficient than storing on the heap?

Comment: @IllidanS4 It's more efficient, because it means you don't have to GC the object afterwards. And you also have one less level of indirection.